# Magento 2 need to Display the popup in checkout when product is orderedqty is greate than product qty or outofstock?

Tags: checkout, magento-2.2.5

In magento 2 need to display the popup in checkout page when is orderedqty is greate than product qty or outofstock ?

You can see in below image popup example.in this we have the two buttons and when we are click any one we need to save the information

[image]

any one please help me?

Comment: what you have try for this?

Comment: i tried for this created the extension attribute but i am struck at display the popup
trying for save the partial shipment information.

Comment: are you facing the issue with saveing information or what?

Comment: no i am not facing any issue,i need to implement this type of popup when product is outofstock

Comment: After which section you need to show this poop-up on checkout?

Comment: after shipping section or click on place order

Comment: @RamSampathi I would suggest creating a place order before event. Check if each order items is in stock or not in that observer. If any item not in stock render new layout block using $layout = $observer->getLayout(); $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('custom_layout_handle');  (Check this to render new layout https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/228406/45214) In that layout block, add template file containing your form, form action (to save button submit) and buttons. You can copy point number 4 and 6 of https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/222160/45214 . I think this can be done by this way.